# Better chunking regex to cater for short strings?

Tags: regex

We are chunking up a large number of file name strings like `"a12345"` into `"a1/23/a12345.png"` to cater for per-folder quantity limits. All names had an enforced minimum length, but a conceptual change led to them now being as small as 1 character, breaking our old approach. How can we change this nginx.conf regex to keep its old behavior when possible, but turn e.g. `"a"` into e.g. `"/a/a/a.png"`? Thanks!

```
listen 80;
# ...snip...
rewrite  "([\w]{2})([\w]{2})([\w]{1,})" /$1/$2/$1$2$3.png;
```

Comment: Did you try something like `rewrite  "^(\w)$" /$1/$1/$1.png last; rewrite  "^(\w{2})$" /$1/$1/$1.png last; rewrite  "^([\w]{2})([\w]{2})([\w]{1,})$" /$1/$2/$1$2$3.png last;`

Comment: @Abecee That looks good, could you please explain what it does? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try something like

```
listen 80;
# ...
rewrite  "^(\w)$" /$1/$1/$1.png last;
rewrite  "^(\w{2})$" /$1/$1/$1.png last;
rewrite  "^([\w]{2})([\w]{2})([\w]{1,})$" /$1/$2/$1$2$3.png last;
```

- It uses anchors for the beginning (`^`) and the end (`$`) of the checked line, respectively - to ensure, the whole line is checked/consumed.
- The `last` flag indicates, no further rule should be applied as soon as a match was found. (You might want to order them based on the likelihood of being matched.)

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.

Comment: Thank you. Upvoted & will mark as answer once we have evidence it works (right now it doesn't, but that may well be due to other issues on our server, and your answer may be perfect, waiting for the server guru on more).